# Defining Algebraic Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots

An algebraic number is a number that is a root of a polynomial with rational coefficients. Any finite combination of rational numbers that can be combined with the usual four operations +, -, *, /, and rational powers can be shown to be an algebraic number. However, not all algebraic numbers can be so defined. So is it possible to write such an algebraic number? It is certainly possible to define a countable infinite of transcendental numbers but not these?

Comment: You are looking for an algebraic number generating an extension which is not solvable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Solvable_groups_and_solution_by_radicals). This should be true of a "generic" irreducible polynomial of degree $5$ or higher (that is, write down a random irreducible polynomial of degree $5$ or higher, and odds are its roots are not solvable).

Comment: That to me is not writing a number. I guess a larger question is why we cannot write such a number? Maybe we need new symbols instead of the rational roots if that is what is required.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what Abel-Ruffini says (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem): we need new symbols. So what symbols are you willing to admit?

Comment: Maybe not symbols but how about a decimal expansion like was used to generate the first transcendental number.

Comment: How are you allowing the decimal expansion to be described? Given any polynomial there is an algorithm which will, given $n$, output the first $n$ digits of the decimal expansions of the roots.

Comment: Good point. But there does not seem to be a procedure to define the decimal expansion other than the output of some numerical algorithm to solve for the roots. I was again thinking of the decimal expansion of a transcendental number. I guess this is not possible.

Comment: In some constructive approaches to mathematics, real numbers are defined exactly by procedures that give their decimal expansions on demand, as precise as needed.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you mean by *write*. The solutions of $ x^5 − x − 1=0$ are certainly algebraic numbers but they cannot be expressed with an algebraic formula like you describe. (This example is mentioned in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#A_non-solvable_quintic_example).)